# Error: Could not enable swapfile `1`: no such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, swap

I'm running a Pi3 with a Raspbian OS and with a swapspace package which automatically manages the swapfile processes for you on start up

I'm using its default config and in trying to run a docker container I keep getting the subject error and sometimes

> Error: Could not enable swapfile `1`: Input/Output error

I'm not too knowledgable with this stuff so I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone explain what this means/ what's going on?

Comment: I don't think a docker container could manage its own swapspace.

Comment: I realize @wurtel but I did not think it had too seeing as the host is managing it ....is it that docker containers are restricted to a max limit regardless of host size?